# How to get Cancelled Accounts via Google Ads API?

Tags: google-ads-api

Using Google Ads API "Get Account Hierarchy" to get all accounts.
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/get-account-hierarchy?hl=en

Found out that **canceled accounts** are not being retrieved.

I do see the canceled accounts are being reported in the UI and in their Google Data Studio connector.
I guess both use the old AdWords API.

Is there a way to fetch and report canceled accounts via Google Ads API?
Is it recommended to use the old AdWords API?

Comment: I'm confident their UI doesn't use the old API. Rather, it is powered by a private API which is different from both the AdWords and Google Ads APIs, hence multiple functionalities are unavailable through the public APIs. Are you sure AdWords API returns canceled accounts? I'm not, to be honest. However, you are [safe](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start) to use AdWords API, it's supported. Anyway, make sure to ask the same question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-api). Google engineers will help you. They always do, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Google Ads team answered: Unfortunately, cancelled accounts will not be returned in either of the APIs.
For more information, you may refer to this blog post (https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/changes-to-inactive-adwords-accounts.html).
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get a list of cancelled accounts yet, fortunately, there is a way to retrieve the list in three steps (according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/listing-accounts?hl=en)):

1. Retrieve the list of ACTIVE links using the customer_client_link
   resource and make a list of customers using the
   customer_client_link.client_customer field.

   ```
    SELECT customer_client_link.client_customer, customer_client_link.status 
      FROM customer_client_link 
     WHERE customer_client_link.status = ACTIVE
   ```
2. Retrieve the list of ENABLED accounts using the customer_client
   resource.

   ```
    SELECT customer_client.id, customer_client.descriptive_name 
      FROM customer_client
   ```
3. The difference between the two lists gives you the list of cancelled
   accounts.